# Add image 'src' to '<a>' tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-cycle

I am using the JQuery [Cycle Plugin with thumbnails](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/pager2.html). This works fine if I use images as my slides. But I want to wrap these images in `<a>` tags. This breaks the thumbnail as the code looks for the `src` within the first, parent element of each slide and of course the `a` tag does not have this. eg:

```
//THUMBNAILS    
pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) { 
        return '<li><a href="#"><img src="' + slide.src + '" width="145" height="88" /></a></li>'; 
    }
```

What I want to do is somehow attach the image's `src` to its parent element, so that the above code can read it. Something like:

```
<a href="page.html" class="slide" src="image.jpg"><img src="image.jpg"></a>
```

But it seems my browser automatically detects this is incorrect and renders it out.

Does anyone know a way to get round this?

Comment: FYI, `src` [is not a valid attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) for the `<a>` tag.

Comment: You might wanna use `data-src`. `data-*` attributes are allowed pretty much anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this when you finished rendering the page:

```
$("img").each(function(){
  var imgSrc = $(this).attr("src");
  $(this).parent().attr("src", imgSrc );
});
```

It will loop all `img` tags and then copy their `src` attribute to their immediate parent.